# How to make a div fullScreen with a bakcground image using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a page where i can have a div fullscreen with a background image using bootstrap just like [Endomodo's site](https://www.endomondo.com/)

Since i just begin boostrap i downloaded some samples on [startboostrap website](http://startbootstrap.com/) and tried to manage what i want. My problem is that the menu and the content are shown in the page but my div doesn't (and so the image).
My html/css :

```css
body {
    margin-top: 50px; /* Required margin for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
}

/* Header Image Background - Change the URL below to your image path (example: ../images/background.jpg) */

.full {
    background: url(bg3.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

.header-image {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    background: url('http://placehold.it/1900x500') no-repeat center center scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}

.headline {
    padding: 120px 0;
}

.headline h1 {
    font-size: 130px;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

.headline h2 {
    font-size: 77px;
    background: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
}

.featurette-divider {
    margin: 80px 0;
}

.featurette {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.featurette-image.pull-left {
    margin-right: 40px;
}

.featurette-image.pull-right {
    margin-left: 40px;
}

.featurette-heading {
    font-size: 50px;
}

footer {
    margin: 50px 0;
}

@media(max-width:1200px) {
    .headline h1 {
        font-size: 140px;
    }

    .headline h2 {
        font-size: 63px;
    }

    .featurette-divider {
        margin: 50px 0;
    }

    .featurette-image.pull-left {
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .featurette-image.pull-right {
        margin-left: 20px;
    }

    .featurette-heading {
        font-size: 35px;
    }
}

@media(max-width:991px) {
    .headline h1 {
        font-size: 105px;
    }

    .headline h2 {
        font-size: 50px;
    }

    .featurette-divider {
        margin: 40px 0;
    }

    .featurette-image {
        max-width: 50%;
    }

    .featurette-image.pull-left {
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .featurette-image.pull-right {
        margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .featurette-heading {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}

@media(max-width:768px) {
    .container {
        margin: 0 15px;
    }

    .featurette-divider {
        margin: 40px 0;
    }

    .featurette-heading {
        font-size: 25px;
    }
}

@media(max-width:668px) {
    .headline h1 {
        font-size: 70px;
    }

    .headline h2 {
        font-size: 32px;
    }

    .featurette-divider {
        margin: 30px 0;
    }
}

@media(max-width:640px) {
    .headline {
        padding: 75px 0 25px 0;
    }

    .headline h1 {
        font-size: 60px;
    }

    .headline h2 {
        font-size: 30px;
    }
}

@media(max-width:375px) {
    .featurette-divider {
        margin: 10px 0;
    }

    .featurette-image {
        max-width: 100%;
    }

    .featurette-image.pull-left {
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .featurette-image.pull-right {
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        margin-left: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<!-- Make sure the <html> tag is set to the .full CSS class. Change the background image in the full.css file. -->

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Full - Start Bootstrap Template</title>
  
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="css/full.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <div class="full">

    </div>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <!-- First Featurette -->
        <div class="featurette" id="about">
            <img class="featurette-image img-circle img-responsive pull-right" src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
            <h2 class="featurette-heading">This First Heading
                <span class="text-muted">Will Catch Your Eye</span>
            </h2>
            <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
        </div>

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <!-- Second Featurette -->
        <div class="featurette" id="services">
            <img class="featurette-image img-circle img-responsive pull-left" src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
            <h2 class="featurette-heading">The Second Heading
                <span class="text-muted">Is Pretty Cool Too.</span>
            </h2>
            <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
        </div>

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <!-- Third Featurette -->
        <div class="featurette" id="contact">
            <img class="featurette-image img-circle img-responsive pull-right" src="http://placehold.it/500x500">
            <h2 class="featurette-heading">The Third Heading
                <span class="text-muted">Will Seal the Deal.</span>
            </h2>
            <p class="lead">Donec ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo.</p>
        </div>

        <hr class="featurette-divider">

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <p>Copyright &copy; Your Website 2014</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>

    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Difficult to tell what you are looking for. You can just apply a background image to a div and it will look like Endomodo's site - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MKqdKj. Note: they apply a height to the div so that it is the size of the browser viewport, that would be done in JavaScript.

Comment: I already checked it out, it doesn't fit with bootstrap. I'm trying to get a responsive view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make a div full size in bootstrap you need to use the container-fluid class. You can get a full page width responsive image div by using the following code.

```
    <div class="container-fluid" style="padding: 0">
    <div class="banner img-responsive"
        style="background-image: url('http://res.cloudinary.com/dhlsxlkrc/image/upload/v1447118604/spring-purple-flowers-1080p-hd_dg4ncq.jpg'); height: 400px;">
</div>
```

So put this code in where you have `<div class="full"></div>`

Comment: I delete my <div class="full"></div> and replaced it by your snippet but it didn't work! :(

Comment: Do you have any working snippet code that i can relay to?

Comment: I'm working on getting you some working code. Hang tight.

Comment: I just added some stuff to the code above and it worked with the code you provided.  I just did inline css but you can pull that out.  You can't pull the background-image: url() out though.

Comment: The code in this answer does as it should. If you have an issue with it please be more specific than "it didn't work" @Habchi

Comment: Okey so i tried your code i can see the image but it fit only a part of the screen, it's the 400px height that create the problem. What i'm trying to get is the image covering the screen.

Comment: Did you remove the padding on the container? When I run the code I am able to fill the full screen with that code I provided.